# Как изменить иконку menu-item в toolbar android?

Tags: android

У меня есть выпадающий список со списком языков, которые можно выбирать, и будет меняться язык приложения. Для списка я использую адаптер:

```
public class CountryListArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<CountrycodeActivity.Country> {

    private final List<CountrycodeActivity.Country> list;
    private final Activity context;

    static class ViewHolder {
        protected TextView name;
        protected ImageView flag;
    }

    CountryListArrayAdapter(Activity context, List<CountrycodeActivity.Country> list) {
        super(context, R.layout.activity_countrycode_row, list);
        this.context = context;
        this.list = list;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {
        View view;

        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflator = context.getLayoutInflater();
            view = inflator.inflate(R.layout.activity_countrycode_row, null);
            final ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
            viewHolder.name = view.findViewById(R.id.name);
            viewHolder.flag = view.findViewById(R.id.flag);
            view.setTag(viewHolder);
        } else {
            view = convertView;
        }

        ViewHolder holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
        holder.name.setText(list.get(position).getName());
        holder.flag.setImageDrawable(list.get(position).getFlag());
        return view;
    }
}
```

и класс:

```
public class CountrycodeActivity extends ListActivity {

    public static String RESULT_CONTRYCODE = "countrycode";
    public String[] countrynames;
    private TypedArray imgs;
    private List<Country> countryList;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        populateCountryList();
        ArrayAdapter<Country> adapter = new CountryListArrayAdapter(this, countryList);
        setListAdapter(adapter);
        getListView().setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                Country c = countryList.get(position);
                Intent returnIntent = new Intent();
                returnIntent.putExtra(RESULT_CONTRYCODE, c.getName());
                setResult(RESULT_OK, returnIntent);
                imgs.recycle();
                finish();
            }
        });
    }

    private void populateCountryList() {
        countryList = new ArrayList<>();
        countrynames = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.country_names);
        imgs = getResources().obtainTypedArray(R.array.country_flags);
        for(int i = 0; i < countrynames.length; i++){
            countryList.add(new Country(countrynames[i], imgs.getDrawable(i)));
        }
    }

    public class Country {
        private String name;
        private Drawable flag;
        Country(String name, Drawable flag){
            this.name = name;
            this.flag = flag;
        }
        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }
        public Drawable getFlag() {
            return flag;
        }
    }
}
```

и дальше при выборе я хочу менять иконку менюшки при нажатии на которую у меня появляется список:

```
@Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();
        switch (id) {

            case R.id.lang:
                Intent intent = new Intent(this, CountrycodeActivity.class);
                startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
                return true;

            case R.id.support:
                Intent error = new Intent(this, Problem.class);
                startActivity(error);
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if (requestCode == 1 && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            String countryCode = data.getStringExtra(CountrycodeActivity.RESULT_CONTRYCODE);
            String lang = "en";
            ImageView imageView = findViewById(R.id.flag);
            sp = getSharedPreferences("language", MODE_PRIVATE);
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sp.edit();
            switch (countryCode) {
                case "English":
                    lang = "en";
                    editor.putString("language", lang);
                    imageView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.if_united_states_flat);
                    break;
                case "Русский":
                    lang = "ru";
                    imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.if_russia_flat);
                    editor.putString("language", lang);
                    break;
                case "Українська":
                    lang = "uk";
                    imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_ukraine);
                    editor.putString("language", lang);
                    break;
            }
            editor.apply();
            changeLang(lang);
        }
    }
```

пробовал так:

```
imageView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.if_united_states_flat);
```

дальше пробовал так:

```
imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.if_russia_flat);
```

но у меня почему-то ошибка вылетает:

```
Process: com.example.developer_4.test_login, PID: 8799
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=1, result=-1, data=Intent { (has extras) }} to activity {com.example.developer_4.test_login/com.example.developer_4.test_login.LoginActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.ImageView.setBackgroundResource(int)' on a null object reference
```

и вот строка на которую указывает ошибка:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.ImageView.setBackgroundResource(int)' on a null object reference
        at com.example.developer_4.test_login.LoginActivity.onActivityResult(LoginActivity.java:193)
```

вот строка в классе:

```
imageView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.if_united_states_flat);
```

### UPDATE

ошибка при выборе пункта меню:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'android.view.MenuItem android.view.MenuItem.setIcon(int)' on a null object reference
```

Comment: Картинки с именами ``if_united_states_flat`` и ``if_russia_flat`` имеются?

Comment: да, они и так используются, но в других задачах, я хочу их здесь использовать тоже

Comment: Текст ошибки говорит, что таких картинок нет. Там точно в названии "if", а не "ic"?

Comment: да, именно эти картинки с `if`

Comment: вы что то писали про элемент разметки? или у меня глюк какой-то?

Comment: Да, подумал, что вероятно отсутствует элемент "R.id.flag", но тогда ошибка была бы в другом месте.

Comment: вот в этом и прикол, что вроде все есть, но все-равно нуль пишет

Comment: А где у Вас `ImageView` с `id` `flag` находится. Судя по ошибке в разметке активности (`LoginActivity`) её нет.

Comment: упс)) да ее нету, я вообще хочу получить доступ не к imageview в определенном layout, я хочу поменять иконку в менюшке на тулбаре. может можно как-то получить к ней доступ, потому-что я по id найти не смог

Comment: Всё-таки нет такого `id` в Вашем меню. Может это `R.id.lang` по нажатию которого запускается выбор языка?

Comment: @woesss, вы как-всегда оказались правы, но изменение в `id` привело только к тому что приложение теперь не крашится, что уже хорошо))

Comment: так, так есть обновленная информация, после выбора пункта меню, у меня на секунду появляется нужная мне картинка, но я так понял она потом пропадает из-за того что пересоздается активити, может можно как-то решить эту проблему?

Comment: Так, активность после выбора языка однозначно пересоздаётся, да? Тогда те две строки кода, что в `onActivityResult`нужно перенести туда, где Вы задаёте сохранённый ранее язык (при старте активности).

Comment: какие две строки? я думал что только одну, там где мы вызываем функцию  `inavalidateOptionsMenu`. Просто мне ведь нужно ставить определенную картинку, которая отвечает языку, а не заданную. Или условия впихнуть прийдется?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Получается что иконка зависит от выбранного языка и система может сама подхватить нужную как и любой другой локализованный ресурс. Для этого нужно картинки флагов поместить в папки с соответствующим языковым квалификатором и задать им одно и тоже имя, например:

```
res/
    drawable-ru-mdpi/
        flag.png  // флаг России
    drawable-ua-mdpi/
        flag.png  // флаг Украины
```

И так далее для всех стран и плотностей(dpi)...
Теперь Вы просто задали иконку в xml:

```
android:icon="@drawable/flag"
```

И система сама будет выбирать флаг в зависимости от выбранного языка - никакого дополнительного кода не нужно.

Comment: я сейчас попробую, если что, то напишу, а то я пока не все детали понял, но самое главное, ваш предыдущий вариант не использовать?

Comment: С точки зрения правил локализации ресурсов - этот вариант правильнее.

Comment: а создавать папки в корне папки `drawable` или раскидывать все как-то по-другому?

Comment: Так понятней (см. ответ)?

Comment: вроде все работает, спасибо большое, но есть один вопрос - это что получается нужно сделать огроменную кучу папок с одной единственное картинкой? для каждого языка?

Comment: Так уж устроена работа с ресурсами в Андроиде - для поддержки разных конфигураций нужно клепать кучу папок. Но в этом больше плюсов. Определением конкретного ресурса для текущей конфигурации занимается система - Вы просто говорите: "дай мне флаг" и не заботитесь о том, какой именно нужен в данный момент. Всё разложено по своим местам - другой человек сможет найти и изменить ресурсы нужной локали без Ваших объяснений. Добавление новых флагов не потребует дополнительного кода для работы с ними.

Comment: да я очень благодарен вам за такой рабочий способ, оказалось что без лишних телодвижений можно получить нужный функционал)

Answer (score 2):

Попробуйте - не проверял, но по логике должно сработать:

```
// объявляем поле, в котором будем хранить выбранный ресурс
private int flagRes = -1;

// переопределяем метод подготовки меню
// в нём находим наш MenuItem
// и меняем картинку если задана (!= -1)
@Override
public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    if (flagRes != -1) {
        menu.findItem(R.id.flag).setIcon(flagRes);
    }
    return true;
}
```

В `onActivityResult`

```
// записываем в поле id нужной картинки
flagRes = R.drawable.<выбранный ресурс>;
// просим активность пересоздать меню
invalidateOptionsMenu();
```

Comment: при переопределении метода приложение слетает, пишет что в функцию передается нулевой параметр. Может я что-то не учел?

Comment: В `findItem(...)` нужно передать `id` того `MenuItem`, которому надо поменять иконку, по Вашему коду мне показалось что это `R.id.flag`

Comment: да, @woesss, вы правы это `id` называется `flag` но почему-то все-равно нуль выводит, сейчас скорее всего дополню ответ, или здесь закину код ошибки.